# Getting the connectionstring in .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to get a connection string from the `app.config` file.

`connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBEntities"];`

But it doesn't work. It's empty.

I cannot access the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` because it's .NET 4.
How can I get my connection string from the `app.config`?

Comment: can you post your web.config with the connectionstring section

Comment: ConfigurationManager isnt an option in .net 4

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
```

Make sure to add reference to `System.configuration` in your project.

Answer (score 8):

In .net 4 you have to use:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name of connection string in web.config"]
```

More about it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder_members.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx).

Comment: +1 but the question is tagged with `c#` so instead of `()` you want `[]`

Answer (score 5):

Add a reference to System.Configuration to your project and use ConnectionStrings instead of AppSettings